# Second order homogenous differential equation with change of variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this differential equation  $$x^2y''+3xy'+y=0$$ With x > 0

I'm told to use the change of variables $x=e^t$

How should I proceed?

Thanks

Comment: It's Cauchy-Euler 's differential equation.

Comment: If the $x$ and $x^2$ factors were not there you would try $y=e^{\lambda x}$ ... this ones different ... for this one try $y=x^{\color{red}{n}}$

Comment: I have to solve it using the change of variables they provide me. I'm sure there are better ways but I'm asked to do it like this.

Comment: I guess I have to do stuff with differentials to get y'' and y' with the change of variable but I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh right ... Chain rule ...

Comment: Yes that's right. I guess y' would be $$dy/dx * dx/dt = dy/dx * e^t$$ but what about y'' ?

Comment: $y''$ is slightly trickier ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{dt}{dx} \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{dt}{dx} \frac{dy}{dt} \right) = e^{-t} \frac{d}{dt} \left( e^{-t} \frac{dy}{dt} \right) =\cdots
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
x^{2}y'' + 3xy' + y = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2}y'' +2xy') + (xy' + y) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2}y')' + (xy)' = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x^{2}y' + xy = k
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes ! Thank you very much

Comment: No worries, I am glad to help!